# What's the best way to use AJAX inside PHP?

Tags: php, ajax, twitter, get, lightbox

I'm trying to build a Twitter-like AJAX feature. I will try to explain what I would like to build.

> When you go to Twitter (and you're logged in) and you click on a
>   Twitter-name you'll get a lightbox with info about the Twitter
>   account.

This is the way I think it works:

When you make a click event on a link the lightbox gets activated. In that same process a file gets called with all the data that's connected to that link.

Now this sounds too easy, do I need to make multiple files for each source? And what's the best file to use? XML, PHP file with an array of just a text file?

Hope someone can explain to me how this process works.

Comment: I don't know what best practices are but I don't like having a different source file for every action. I usually seperate out my scripts logically between different files (ex: admin-ajax.php, public-ajax.php) and have a big switch statement that passes an action variable through the ajax call. As far as the implementation goes, I think the answer below gives more information than I would :)

Answer (score 1):

You would probably want to use a database for that, that holds information about your users. That will probably be a lot easier for you to maintain, an most likely have better performance as well.

You then call a single file (be it PHP, ASP.Net, Node or whatever server-side language you prefer) to which you provide the ID of the user you are interested in (send it as an HTTP POST or GET variable).

The file you call will then go do the database, fetch information about the user you requested, and return it in a suitable format (JSON or XML for instance). The same file will be called no matter what user you want information about.

IBM has [an article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-jquery-ajax/index.html) on how to build an Ajax-driven web app using PHP and jQuery. Unfortunately the way they interact with the DB is somewhat old, now days it preferred to use use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), but apart from that, I believe it could be a good starting point for you.

Comment: @BramBoersma Sure, either you roll your own AJAX-functionality like that. Or you use can use the AJAX-feature in a library like [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), or some other library that provide similar functionality.

Comment: Please don't use w3schools. That is a really, really bad example. With security issues and really bad practices. http://www.phptherightway.com/#databases

Comment: @WayneC Agree, the PHP in that example is worse then terrible!